# VBA Excel 2019, menus created by commandbars are not lisible

Tags: vba, menu

I created a menu in VBA under Excel 2019 with CommandBars. No programmation problem, all works fine.

But the menu appears to be of a different style than the usual excel menus: Black (Enabled) is grey, grey (Disabled) if very light, the separator line (BeginGroup) is so light than it's quite invisible.

I wonder if it is because CommandBars are deprecated, and Microsoft wants to discourage programmers to use it.